# How Do I Set The A Record In Office365?

Tags: domain-name-system, microsoft-office-365

Microsoft is managing my email via Office365 and the nameserver is NS1.BDM.MICROSOFTONLINE.COM.

Now I am creating a website using stablehost as the hosting provider.

However, if I change the nameserver to the stablehost nameserver my emails start bouncing.

Stablehost provided my with an IP for the A Record instead.

However, I can't see where to put this in the Office365 Admin Panel.

The Settings -> Domains menu only gives me options for MX, CNAME, TXT and SRV.

Comment: You CAN move dns over to wherever you like, you know - I use cloudflare - and just enter corresponding MX entries to forward the emails to MS.

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is managed by Office 365 you have the option to enter a Custom Record where you can enter the A record.

However, if the domain is managed externally you only have the option to edit the records mentioned in the question. i.e. MX, CNAME, TXT and SRV.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Sign in to Office 365 account.
- Choose Setup > Domains.
- Click Domains on Office 365 Admin page
- On the Domains page, select a domain.
- Under DNS settings, choose Custom Records, and then choose New custom
  record.
- Click Customer records 5. Choose the type of DNS record you want to
  add, and type the information for the new record.
- Choose Save.

Good luck!